# ¿Como cambio un una cadena de numero obtenida $ _POST a un arreglo?

Tags: php, ajax, array, post

Cuando obtengo el valor de un arreglo de **checkbox** para enviarlo por **Ajax** lo hace bien '(3) [1, 2, 3]'  pero cuando lo obtengo en el php `$seleccionados=$_POST['seleccionados'];` lo obtengo de esta manera `'1,2,3'` y no lo puedo recorre, como lo convierto de nuevo a un arreglo ya lo trate de poner dentro de `array()` pero no funciono,por favor ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que te llega en `$_POST['seleccionados']` es un *string* como indicas `"1,2,3"` puedes usar [*explode*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) para crear un *array*.

El primer argumento es el separador, el segundo es el *string* que quieres convertir.

```
$seleccionados = explode(',', $_POST['seleccionados']);
```

El resultado será como tener algo así:

```
$seleccionados = array(
    "1",
    "2",
    "3",
);
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias me funciono muy bien, eres genial.